# tensorflow, remove duplicate

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 1-d tensor like:

```
[1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
```

How to get `[1,2,3,4,5]` from it?

My solution is:

I need a tensorflow API similar to `contains`.

Then I could put the individual one into `TensorArray`.

Comment: I never used tensorflow but I was able to find this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique with 3 seconds of googling.

Comment: @timgeb I'm in China and I can not google...

Comment: wow, sorry, didn't consider. Can you follow the link?

Comment: @timgeb Thank you, I will try `tf.unique`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You a are looking for `tf.unique`. Quoting directly from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique):

```
# tensor 'x' is [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8]
y, idx = unique(x)
y ==> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
idx ==> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```